# Tracking online visitors per page in a website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services

Is there a way to track the number of online visitors for each page in my website? I want to pop something like "There are 6 people viewing this page right now" when a visitor enters this page.

Comment: Depends on what do you mean as visitor. You can track clicks by GA as stated in answers. If you have database, you can track your registered users by their last impression, which should be saved in db field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build something not much complex using SignalR and javascript.

A javascript in each page would inform the SignalR service that someone is in there and the server would aggregate it and broadcast it to everyone that is in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following reference links:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29792/Online-active-users-counter-in-ASP-NET
http://graysoft.blogspot.in/2009/02/howto-get-current-online-users-count.html

Comment: Thank you for these useful links, but I think that they are talking about online users all over the web site. My issue is to count online users for each page